# How to convert Date (from google sheet data) to TimeStamp (Firestore) using AppScript?

Tags: database, firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-api

I've got a date object in Google Sheet which I want to import to firestore as a timestamp object, but it doesn't work when I do it directly.

[image: Google Sheets image]
If I enter the current date,

```
 data.date = new Date(dateSt);
```

it stores an empty map object in firestore.
[image]

What should I do to convert the date object to timestamp.

Full Code:

```
function classRoutineFunction() {
   const email = "my_email";
   const key = "my_private_key";
   const projectId = "my_projectID";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);


  // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

  // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
       var data = {};
       var dateSt = sourceData[i][0].toString();
       var stDate = new Date(dateSt);
       var stringfied = JSON.stringify(stDate);
       var updatedDt = stringfied.slice(1,11);

       data.date = new Date(dateSt);
       data.time = sourceData[i][1];
       data.batch = sourceData[i][2];
       data.topic = sourceData[i][3];

       firestore.createDocument("classRoutine",data);
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Why tag Excel? are you working in excel?

Comment: I am working on Google Sheets, sorry for the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your date value is a `dates` and not a `String`.
Use `DATEVALUE` to convert a String to a date the FirestoreApp can interpret as a timestamp.

**Bonus:** 
If you use `=DATEVALUE('2020-07-11') + TIMEVALUE('18:00:00)` it will add the time to the timestamp in Firestore.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when you use the library. But if you copy & paste the library to your project and run it from there, it works (or at least it worked for me). Don't ask me why :'D

Comment: And please note, you should be passing the original value (without modification), like so:
`data.date = sourceData[i][0];`

Comment: Yes I am using the original value without modification, still doesnt work. Thank you though for your answer

Comment: DATEVALUE is not defined..? Any answers please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the library by "graham" 1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw
The bug is fixed when using version 30 for me.