# How to set the id of document of firestore using google sheets

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a table in google sheets which I want to upload to the firstore using a custom document id to prevent data duplication. How can I change the id of the document.

Full Code:

```
function classRoutineFunction() {
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);


  // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

  // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
       var data = {};
       var dateSt = sourceData[i][0].toString();
       var stDate = new Date(dateSt);
       var stringfied = JSON.stringify(stDate);
       var updatedDt = stringfied.slice(1,11);

       data.date = updatedDt;
       data.time = sourceData[i][1];
       data.batch = sourceData[i][2];
       data.topic = sourceData[i][3];
       data._id = dateStr + batch; // Want to set a custom id

       firestore.createDocument("classRoutine",data);
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: I see a few libraries that allow you to access Firestore from Apps Script. Can you provide a link to the library you are using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the name of the new document into the string argument when calling `createDocument`. From the documentation on [creating documents in Firestore from your script](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#create-a-test-document-in-firestore-from-your-script):

> Alternatively, we can create the document in the `FirstCollection` collection called `FirstDocument`:
>
> ```
> firestore.createDocument("FirstCollection/FirstDocument", data)
> ```

Here `FirstDocument` is the name of the document in `FirstCollection`.

So for you this would look something like:

```
firestore.createDocument("classRoutine/yourCustomId",data);
```

Comment: Thank you It works perfectly. Can you check if you answer the another query I had.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113437/how-to-convert-date-from-google-sheet-data-to-timestamp-firestore-using-apps